# How is the resolution of round watches calculated?

Tags: android-wear

I'm seeing these Android Wear round watches with specs of like 320x320 resolution.

What does that resolution mean on a circular screen?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the same as square watches, but you can only see about 78.54% of the screen as the corners are cut off.

Square area = width * width

Circle area = PI * 0.5width * 0.5width

Whatever width you use the circle area always ends up being 78.54% (rounded number) of the square area.